# Proving that a Function does not have any extreme points

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity, infinity

I need to find a continuous function, such that $$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=L_{1}$$ $$\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=L_{2}$$

And such that $f$ doesn't have any extreme points.

So I found this function here: $f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|+1}$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I have proved that the function is continuous and also that  $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=-1$.

Now all I left to do is proving that this function has no extreme points at all.

I want to prove that the function is strictly increasing, and for that reason my theorem holds.

I have tried to choose $x_{1}, x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_{1}<x_{1}$ and prove that $f(x_{1})<f(x_{2})$ but I find this difficult for me for some reason.

I will appreciate you help to finish my proof!

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: The standard example of what you want is probably the [Logistic Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).  For your example, note that (for $x>0$) we have $f(x)=1-\frac 1{x+1}$  which is clearly montone increasing.  That's all you need.

Comment: Thank you for that!
I see why for $x>0$, $f$ is monotone increasing, but what about $x \leq 0$?

Comment: Just use $f(-x)=-f(x)$.  Or rewrite $f(x)$ for $x<0$ along the same lines I did

Comment: How do I know that my $f$ is odd?

Comment: I don't understand.  Isn't it obvious?

Comment: Should say;  one reason people prefer the logistic function is that it is smooth, your function isn't.  Depends what you are using it for, obviously, but for many applications it helps to stick with smooth functions.

Comment: I see that. I actually do not familiar with Logistic Function.
For my $f$, I see why it is odd, but now I left with $x=0$, so $f(x)=0$

Comment: Well, if it has limits of $1$ and $-1$ any extreme points it could have would have to be $\ge 1$ or $\le -1$.  So just prove $-1 < \frac {x}{|x| + 1|} < 1$

Comment: [Re](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3978561/proving-that-a-function-does-not-have-any-extreme-points#comment8208805_3978561), you have $f(x_-) = \frac1{1 - x_-} - 1 < 0 = f(0) < 1 - \frac1{x_+ + 1} = f(x_+)$ for $x_- < 0 < x_+$.

Comment: Proving it's increasin is simple.  If $0 \le x < y$ then $0\le \frac {x}{x+1}=1 -\frac 1x < 1-\frac 1y=\frac {x}{x+1}$.  If $x< 0 \le y$ the $\frac x{|x|+1} < 0\le \frac{y}{|y| + 1}$.  An if $x < y < 0$ then $\frac{x}{|x|+1}= -(\frac {|x|}{|x|+1})=-1 +\frac 1{|x|} < -1+\frac 1{|y|} = \frac {y}{|y| + 1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply prove $-1 < \frac {x}{|x| + 1} < 1$ for all $x$.

Thus for any possible $x_0$ we have $-1 < f(x_0) < 1$.

And as $\lim_{x\to \infty} = 1$ we have $x$s where $f(x_0) < f(x) < 1$.

And as $\lim_{x\to -\infty} = -1$ we havve $x$s where $-1 < f(x) < f(x_0)$.

So $f(x_0)$ can not be an extreme value for any $x_0$.

....

If you want to show $f$ is increasing do it in cases

Cases $x < y < 0$, $x < 0 \le y$,  $0\le x < y$.

Note that $\frac {|w|}{|w| + 1} = \frac {|w|+1}{|w|+1} - \frac 1{|w|}=1 -\frac 1{|w|}$

If $0 \le x < y$ then $x=|x|;y=|y|$ and $\frac 1{|y|} < \frac 1{|x|}$ and so $\frac {x}{|x| + 1} =\frac {|x|}{|x|+1} = 1 -\frac 1{|x|} < 1 -\frac 1{|y|} = \frac {y}{|y| + 1}$.

If $x < 0 \le y$ then $\frac {x}{|x|+1} < 0 \le \frac {y}{|x| + 1}$.

And if $x < y < 0$ then $|x| > |y|$ and

$\frac {x}{|x| + 1} = -\frac {|x|}{|x|+1} = -(1-\frac 1{|x|})< -(1-\frac 1{|y|}) = \frac y{|y| + 1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I appreciate that! :)

Answer (score 0):

One we is to prove the function to be derivable for x $\in$ R. Then show derivative > 0.

Comment: $|x|$ does not derivable at $x=0$, so I am not sure if I can use that.

Comment: But the function is derivable. @MathLover

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f\left(x\right)=\frac{e^{x}}{1+e^{x}}$

$f$ is continuous by arithmetic property of continuous functions. Also We have:

$$\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{e^{x}}{1+e^{x}}=1$$

$$\underset{x\rightarrow-\infty}{\lim}\frac{e^{x}}{1+e^{x}}=0$$

$f$ doesn't have a max because for every $x_1\in\mathbb{R}$ we can take $x_1+1$  such that:

$$\underbrace{f\left(x_1+1\right)}=\frac{e^{x_{1}+1}}{1+e^{x_{1}+1}}=\frac{e\cdot e^{x_{1}}}{1+e\cdot e^{x_{1}}}=\frac{e^{x_{1}}}{\frac{1}{e}+e^{x_{1}}}\underset{\frac{1}{e}<1}{\underbrace >}\frac{e^{x_{1}}}{1+e^{x_{1}}}=\underbrace{f\left(x_{1}\right)}$$

Also, $f$ doesn't have a min because for every $x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ we can take $x_2-1$  such that:

$$\underbrace{f\left(x_2-1\right)}=\frac{e^{x_{2}-1}}{1+e^{x_{2}-1}}=\frac{\frac{e^{x_{2}}}{e}}{1+\frac{e^{x_{2}}}{e}}=\frac{e^{x_{2}}}{e+e^{x_{2}}}\underset{e>1}{\underbrace <}\frac{e^{x_{2}}}{1+e^{x_{2}}}=\underbrace{f\left(x_{2}\right)}$$

Comment: This seems to be an example of the phenomenon the question describes, but not a proof that the specific example the OP gives works.

Comment: Correct, but i've seen help is already being given about his example.
In his question, he mentioned that he has to find such a function, I only gave him another option, while proving it works.